# UIScrollView enable paging after screen width goes wider

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview, paging

Here is a screenshot for a `ipad` application below:
[image]

This application contains a `UIScrollView` with several pages. Starting 3 screens, `paging` is enabled. Then a wider screen `Screen 4` comes (There are few more pages after `screen4` and before `screen5` with varying width in the app.) and `paging` is disable there. Now i want to again start `paging` with the start of `Screen 5`. Everything works well if `Screen 4` is also of `width 1024` but if it is wider then enabling `paging` shows `screen 4` and `screen 5` partially.

Is it possible to enable paging from a perticular `x coordinate` onwards?
I already have every coordinate info and for `screen 4`'s `x coordinate` is there a way to start paging from there?

Or is there a way to do not disable paging but increase page size for `Screen 4`?

Comment: Find any solution for this?

Comment: Could you find a solution yet?

Comment: I was unlucky to find any solution on this so we requested a change requirement. :(